# Nested column extraction using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have spent hours trying to un-nest columns in my dataframe coming from a json file and still could not make it work.

I have queried a website using GraphQl and loaded the response into variable json:

```
json = resp.json()
```

Next, I loaded the data into a dataframe using json_normalize:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(resp.json()), orient='columns')
```

I renamed the columns.

However, there were still nested columns within the dataframe - namely 'rules' and 'floors': 
[image]
[image]

I then tried un-nestling the columns through several approaches I have seen here on stackoverflow but also elsewhere on the internet:

I tried the nested column json_normalize in different versions and also with metadata, but none of the ways of calling the specific values worked:

```
  json_normalize(json, ['floors', ['units'],['features']])
```

and this:

```
 json_normalize(data=json, record_path=['floors', 'units','features'])
```

In most cases however, I got TypeError: string indices must be integers.

I tried assigning the values separately to columns but this failed for cases where some of these were NUll

```
df['pets allowed'] = json['data']['offerAggregate']['property_aggregate']['property']['rules']['code' == 'pets-allowed']['exists']
```

I also tried splitting the columns by key words such as 'Code' but this only returned Null

Optimally, I would like to make option #1 work, but I truly tried so many versions and still do not have a result, since I am not sure how to appropriately define the path to the nested column.

Here's the full schema:

```
{'data': {'offerAggregate': {'accommodation_offer': {'contract': {'type': 'fortnight',
     'exclusive': False,
     'is_instant_booking': False,
     'commission': 0.08,
     'deposit': {'pay_to': 'accommodation-provider',
      'type': 'equal-to-first-payment',
      'value': {'amount': 0, 'currency_code': ''}},
     'admin_fee': {'exact_value': True,
      'value': {'amount': 0, 'currency_code': 'EUR'}},
     'fixed_unitary': {'extra_per_guest': {'amount': 0, 'currency_code': ''}}},
    'reference_price': {'amount': '25000', 'currency_code': 'EUR'},
    'requisites': {'conditions': {'cancellation_policy': 'moderate',
      'minimum_nights': 27,
      'max_guests': 2}},
    'costs': {'bills': {'water': {'included': True},
      'electricity': {'included': True},
      'gas': {'included': True},
      'internet': {'included': True}},
     'services': {'cleaning': {'periodicity': 'weekly'}}}},
   'accommodation_provider': {'stats': {'bookings': {'accepted': {'total': 2},
      'requested': {'total': 10},
      'rejected': {'total': 1},
      'confirmed': {'total': 0}}},
    'created': {'at': '2018-11-02 16:51:22'}},
   'property_aggregate': {'property': {'id': '114087',
     'landlord_resident': {'gender': '', 'age_range': '', 'occupation': ''},
     'floors': [{'units': [{'features': [{'Code': 'fridge', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'freezer', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'oven', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'stove', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'washing-machine', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'table', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True}]},
        {'features': [{'Code': 'bathtub', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'shower', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'sink', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'toilet', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True}]},
        {'features': [{'Code': 'wardrobe', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'lock', 'Exists': True}]},
        {'features': [{'Code': 'wardrobe', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'lock', 'Exists': True}]},
        {'features': [{'Code': 'wardrobe', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'lock', 'Exists': True}]},
        {'features': [{'Code': 'wardrobe', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': True},
          {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': False},
          {'Code': 'lock', 'Exists': True}]}]}],
     'rules': [{'code': 'overnight-guests-allowed', 'exists': False},
      {'code': 'pets-allowed', 'exists': False},
      {'code': 'smoking-allowed', 'exists': False}],
     'typology': {'area': 0,
      'accommodation_type_code': 'private',
      'type_code': 'apartment',
      'number_of_bedrooms': 4,
      'number_of_bathrooms': 1},
     'location': {'neighborhood_id': 229,
      'geo': {'latitude': 38.7514768, 'longitude': -9.2031683},
      'address': {'postal_code': '1500-109'}},
     'verification': {'verified': True}}}}}}
```

Thank you for your time in advance! Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think that you really want to use pd.read_json instead:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Hey kevin,  I tried using pd.read_json, but I couldn't apply it since my object is a Python dict. I did not find a way to transform the request response to a true JSON. The command resp.json() seems to have transformed it to a Python object.

Comment: This then returns me a dataframe with 2 columns:
'offerAggregate' in the 'index' column
and the whole rest of the dictionary in the 'data' column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `json_normalize` is stopping at `floors` and `rules` is because they contain `lists` instead of `dictionaries`, which is what `json_normalize` is waiting for.

To normalize this json you will need to convert those lists to dictionary like structures. So for example for rules instead of this structure:

```
[{'code': 'overnight-guests-allowed', 'exists': False},
  {'code': 'pets-allowed', 'exists': False},
  {'code': 'smoking-allowed', 'exists': False}]
```

You will want this structure:

```
{'overnight-guests-allowed': False,
 'pets-allowed': False},
 'smoking-allowed': False}
```

Comment: @HannahKorts That's great happy to hear!